# Where to modify the value of $GEM_PATH?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, rubygems, rvm

My current $GEM_PATH is "/home/me/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.2-p318", and i want to revert it back to ""/home/me/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.2-p290" , what "rc" file do i need to edit .

Thanks!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

as you use rvm:

```
rvm use 1.9.2-p290 --default
```

this will change it for current and next sessions

Comment: Thanks to all responders, i realize that my main fault is not to put the "specific" sort of version(p290) , instead i always do is:

    rvm use 1.9.2 --default

That's why i end up asking the first question i posted, which is to change the $GEM_PATH.

Answer (score 1):

Execute this on your console:

```
export GEM_PATH=/home/me/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.2-p290
```

Comment: Put the export command in your ~/.bash_profile
You can also put in :/etc/init.rd/rc
if you want to change it for all users, edit: /etc/bash.bashrc